# Adding a Jupyter notebook to an IBM Watson Studio project

Tags: jupyter-notebook, watson-studio

Can I add a Jupyter notebook from my local Anaconda environment on my PC to an IBM Watson Studio project or do I have to recreate the notebook in my Watson Studio project from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Use from file option in new notebook screen to upload any Jupyter Notebook that is in .ipynb file format.

Comment: Thank you, this work just as you said. Problem solved.